# require_once issues, when calling functions included in another file

Tags: php, mysql, require-once

here is my problem:

index.php contents:

```
require_once('phpcommonscripts/connections/connection.php');
require_once('phpcommonscripts/functions/logging.php');

    Func_LogToDB($logType, $actionType, $errMsg, $varUser);
```

connection.php contents:

```
$hostname_MYDB = "localhost";
$database_MYDB = "MYDB";
$username_MYDB = "USER";
$password_MYDB = "PASS";
$MYDB = mysql_pconnect($hostname_MYDB, $username_MYDB, $password_MYDB) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

logging.php contents:

```
function Func_LogToDB($lType, $lAction, $lMessage, $lUser) {       
    mysql_select_db($database_MYDB, $MYDB);
}
```

---

ERROR MESSAGE:

Notice: Undefined variable: database_MYDB in /home/notes/public_html/phpcommonscripts/functions/logging.php on line 22

( line 22 is the mysql_select_db() line... )

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: You should read up on [variable scope with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong here ?

Yes you are :)

Those variables `$database_MYDB, $MYDB` aren't in same [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You cannot access variables which are defined outside a function from within a function.

Comment: @user1032650: You can make them `global` but that is NOT advised.

Comment: i added these two lines at logging.php:
  global $database_NOTES;
  global $NOTES;
and works fine now. why would it not be advised what i did?

Comment: @user1032650: For more info about why `global` is considered bad practice see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why